# Switch Hosts With Gmail Account Attached

Tags: domains, dns, email, nameserver

I am transferring a client from their old host to my new one. Their domain-based gmail/apps account was connected to their old host, so when I changed the domain's name servers to the new host, naturally the gmail account stopped working.

So I added the 7 MX records tho the new host's DNS and verified I own the domain on the new host's FTP but the email still isn't working. Is there something I'm missing?

I added the MX records to the new host about two hours ago, is it possible it just takes longer than that? Also, outgoing mail seems to work. Members of the domain can't receive email though, just sends back an error.

Thanks, Wade

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/20123/how-long-will-a-dns-change-take

Comment: Let us know if this has been resolved (i.e. if the DNS records have propagated or some other solution has been found).

Answer (score 1):

Officially it takes up to 48 hours to propagate throughout the world, but for me changes have never taken more than 6 hours.

If it's still not working now, you should look at whether you made any mistakes setting the DNS records. You can also try these services to make sure it's working from other places:

- [CheckDNS.net](http://www.checkdns.net/quickcheckdomainf.aspx)
- [MXToolbox.com](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/) (for MX records)

Answer (score 0):

It can take up to 48 hours for dns settings to transfer/become correct. Didn't you read the warnings on both your host and google?

Comment: I know it can take that long but doing a lookup and using my ftp, it seems to have transferred successfully. The lookup shows the new nameservers and all the google MX records. Do you still think that's the problem though, it just needs a bit of time?

Comment: Or do you mean that MX records as well can take 48 hours to register with google?

Comment: both. You may have to go into the apps cp and attempt to refresh (not sure how)